# ggplot fills in data in the wrong order

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to do something like a calendar plot, but with hours over a month (instead of days over a year). I managed to do this with ggplot, but the data gets filled in in the wrong order.

I made this reproducable example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
device <- "test"
dat <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=31*24, ncol=2))
dat[,1] <- seq.POSIXt(from=(as.POSIXct("2016-12-01 00:00:00")), length.out=(31*24), by="1 hour")
dat[,2] <- seq(from=1, to=nrow(dat), by=1)
colnames(dat) <- c("Zeit", device)

dat$month<-as.numeric(as.POSIXlt(dat$Zeit)$mon+1)
dat$monthf<-factor(dat$month)
dat$monthf<-factor(dat$month,levels=as.character(1:12),labels=c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"),ordered=TRUE)

dat$week <- as.numeric(format(dat$Zeit,"%W"))

dat$weekday = as.POSIXlt(dat$Zeit)$wday
dat$weekdayf<-factor(dat$weekday,levels=(c(1:6,0)),labels=(c("Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun")),ordered=TRUE)

dat$day <- as.numeric(format(dat$Zeit,"%d"))
dat$dayf<-factor(dat$day)

dat$hour <- as.numeric(format(dat$Zeit,"%H"))
dat$hourf<-factor(dat$hour)

plot(ggplot(dat, aes(hourf, week, fill = dat[2])) +
   scale_y_reverse() +
   geom_tile(colour = "white") +
   facet_wrap(monthf~weekdayf, ncol=7) +
   scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("darkgreen", "green", "yellow", "red","darkred"),
                                               values=rescale(c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1)),
                                               guide="colorbar") +
   xlab("") + ylab("") + ggtitle(device)
```

)

This is only an example to show my problem. As you can see, the days itself are correct (december first was an Thursday, december 31th was a Saturday), but the data gets filled in wrong (vertically instead of horicontally).

What am I doing wrong?

[Here you can see the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqvwB.png)

Comment: When using `ggplot()` function you should reference to your column just by their name - repalce `fill =dat[2]` with `fill = test`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably easier to use `facet_grid` instead.

Also, refer to variables by name! So use `test` not `dat[2]`.

If you don't know the variable name and need to set it programmatically, use `aes_string` or `aes_` instead.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(hourf, 1, fill = test)) +
  geom_tile(colour = "white") +
  facet_grid(week~monthf+weekdayf, switch = 'y') +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("darkgreen", "green", "yellow", "red","darkred"),
                       values=rescale(c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1)),
                       guide="colorbar") +
  xlab("") + ylab("") + 
  ggtitle(device) +
  theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank())
```

[image]